# Redux state is updated but mapStateToProps not being called

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactjs-flux

When I change input text value and click the 'save' button,
'category name' will be changed.

---

**CategoryName.js**

```
class CategoryName extends Component {

        render() {
                return (
                    <>  
                       <section className="CategoryName">
                          <div>
                             <div>{this.props.categoryName}</div>
                          </div>
                       </section>
                    </>
                )
        }
 }
    
// react-redux 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.categoryName);
    return {categoryName: state.categoryName}
};
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoryName);
```

---

**/CategoryName/index.js**

```
import {re_modifyCategoryName} from './reducers/index.js'

const store = createStore(re_modifyCategoryName)

class CategoryList extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <>
               <div>
                   <Provider store ={store}>
                      <CategoryName />
                   </Provider>
                   <Provider store ={store}>
                      <CategoryName />
                   </Provider>
               </div>
           </>
        )
    }
}
export {CategoryList}
```

---

**/reducers/index.js**

```
import * as types from '../actions/ActionTypes';

var initialState = {
    categoryName: 'default name in redux'
};



function re_modifyCategoryName(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.MODIFY_CATEGORY_NAME :
            return {
                ...state,
                categoryName : action.categoryName,
            }
            
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

export {re_modifyCategoryName}
```

---

**ModifyCategoryName.js**

```
class ModifyCategoryName extends Component {

    state = {
        categoryName : "default name",
    }

    

    _saveModifyCategoryName = () => {
        
        this.props.onModifyCategoryName(this.state.categoryName)
    }
    
    _onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            categoryName : e.target.value
        })
    }
   
    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <div className="ModifyCategoryName">
                    <div className="ModifyCategoryNameWrapper">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                Header
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input className="ModifyCategoryNameInput" type="text" onChange={this._onChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button onClick={this._saveModifyCategoryName}>save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    
    onModifyCategoryName: (categoryName) => {
        dispatch(actions.modifyCategoryName(categoryName))
    }
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ModifyCategoryName)
```

---

**/ModifyCategoryName/index.js**

```
import {re_modifyCategoryName} from './reducers/index.js'

const store = createStore(re_modifyCategoryName)


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <ModifyCategoryName />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('modify-category-name-modal'))
```

---

**/actions/index.js**

```
import * as types from './ActionTypes';

export const modifyCategoryName = (categoryName) => ({
    type: types.MODIFY_CATEGORY_NAME,
    categoryName
});
```

---

Because I insert `console.log(state.categoryName)` in `const mapStateToProps` at **CategoryName.js** , when the page is rendered first time `'default name in redux'` which is `initialState.categoryName` of `redux store` is shown in console and `{this.props.categoryName}` at **CategoryName.js**. I think this proves that `redux store` connects with **CategoryName.js** well.

Also, when I write text `'change category name'` as new text value of input and click the 'save' button, then dispatch(action) in `_saveModifyCategoryName` at **ModifyCategoryName.js** will be triggered and the state of redux store will be changed by `reducer` . If you see this [image] from my redux-dev-tool, you can check that `'default category name'` is changed to `'change category name'`. I think this proves that `dispatch(action)` and `redux update` goes well.

However as you see image above, the state of redux is updated, but mapStateToProps is not being called.. Definitely, `console.log(state.categoryName)` in `mapStateToProps` is called when the page is rendered first time, but even though `state of redux` is changed, any change isn't shown in `console` and `{this.props.categoryName}` at **CategoryName.js**

What's wrong with me?

Comment: I see you using import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; may be problem heppens there

Comment: Provide more code on createStore and combineReducers

Comment: @egorchik I didn't use `{ combineReducers }`

Comment: @devssh export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoryName); - this is correct

Comment: @devssh, that is also valid

Comment: @1Sun We can't tell "what's wrong with you" as asked in the question XD. As for the code, can you share the action `actions.modifyCategoryName`. I see that redux says your state was updated. That means the problem lies in the connection and so does your "default category name" text appear before you hit save?

Comment: @devssh yes `"default category name"` appear before hit save in `console` and `{this.props.categoryName}` and I write `export default connect(()=>{},mapStateToProps)(CategoryName)` but  it shows error `mapStateToProps() in Connect(CategoryName) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

Comment: That means an error was thrown in the reducer(unlikely since redux plugin shows otherwise) or in the function calls originating from `onChange`. Can you also check the global `state` instead of the `diff` in the redux plugin and share screenshot? You can also add `{console.log(this.props, this.state, "abdc")}` in the render function on every page and it will console.log on every render.

Comment: I suspect this may be a problem with the way the functions are being called in react. for example instead of `_onChange = (e) => {}` try using `_onChange(e) {}` and adding `this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this)` to the `constructor(props){super(props); this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);}` and also move the `this.state` init to constructor. What happens after you click save? Does the screen go blank? Does the default text remain? Are no errors thrown in console?

Comment: Not just for this._onChange can you check by doing this for all methods that start like name = () => {} and change them to name() {} and add a bind in constructor

Comment: @devssh really thanks for reply, I think `onChange` has no problem, when text is changed, its change is directly reflected on `state` However, when I hit save, there is no variation..

Comment: @1Sun can you add `console.log(this.state.categoryName, "catname")` in `_saveModifyCategoryName = () => {}` also you can add a callback to this.setState({someKey: val}, ()=>{console.log("callback", this.state)})

Comment: @devssh I added `console.log(this.state)` in `_saveModifyCategoryName = () => {}` and when I write new text like `'changechange'` and hit save, 'changechange' is shown in `console`!

Comment: Inside your CategoryName.js, you have `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.categoryName);` can you edit to `console.log("inside category name", state.categoryName)`, now if this console.log does not happen on clicking save, that means an error occured in your code. Did you try binding all the functions with this.funcName.bind(this) like I said in all the classes? Please add these strings because with multiple console.log statements I'm not sure if you can tell what is being logged where. If the console.log succeeds there then it will be rendered on your screen.

Comment: You have used provider everywhere, Please learn how to configure store and provider properly

Comment: @devssh I change all arrow functions to what shape you tell me and add  `console.log("inside category name", state.categoryName)` but `"inside category name"` not apper...

Comment: Yes, that's expected, now you know the bug lies in either connect - redux store setup, or reducer, or in the way you are connecting react state with redux state using your save method. Follow the pattern of console.log("custom string per method", this.props, this.state) until you find whats wrong.

Comment: @devssh yes :) it depends on my endeavor, really thanks for your help!

Comment: Are importing the your reducer correctly before passing to the createStore? I see you don't export default.

Comment: @user1505520 I correctly import the reducer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a really foolish.

I have to use `<Provider store ={store} /><Provider />` in the top of component tree.. but I didn't.. then `new components` extracted by `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` do not share same `redux store`.